# Hard drive write speed drops from 150mb/s to 2mb/s when copying large files

Tags: hard-drive

When I copy 600gb of large file videos from hdd F to hdd G, after 100gb are copied, the write speed of hdd G starts dropping from 150mb/s to 1-2mb/s. When I cancel the copying, the drive is still 100% active for a long time as it's continuing writing files (around 2.6gb cache) from memory at 1mb/s.

When the write from memory is finished and hdd G activity goes to 0%, I try to copy files again but then "memory cache" fills up  in seconds and hdd has 1-2mb/s speed almost from the start. So effectively if the drive cloggs up once then it continues being slow even after finishing writing from memory. The only way to fix the slowness is to restart the PC. When I boot again, the system works fine until I copy large files which causes the mentioned slowness.

I've done the same copying experiment on another hdd L and the same issue happens.

I've tried swapping sata cables and plugging into different sata ports but doesnt help.

The motherboard has 6 sata ports, 2x sata3 and 4xsata2. All slots are used for some drives. The drives F G L are plugged into two sata 2 ports. When doing the copying experiments, no other intense processes are running.

Is it motherboard, RAM or hdd issue?

PC: i7 lga1155, asrock pro4, 24gb ram, seagate 4tb drives.

Comment: It seems to be a _caching_ issue of the _Operating System_. What OS do you use?

Comment: Have you tested drives F, G, and L to identify if any of them are suffering from physical failures? That would mean running a full surface scan on them and observing their throughout and statistics during the test.

Comment: I use Windows 10 pro. I've tested F G L surfaces with seagate tools software and they appear to be fine. How can i avoid this caching issue? Hard drives work fine until hundreds of GB are copied, then they kinda of stall. All of them have 50% free space.

Comment: Windows file copy for large jobs has always been lack luster in performance, try a third party tool>>>>>>>https://www.thewindowsclub.com/free-fast-file-copy-software-for-windows-10-pc

Answer (score 3):

One of the answers explained that my drive issues are happening because the drive is using SMR technology and this is absolutely correct. SMR drives can slow down to a halt when re-writing files. They are terrible for desktops.

I've tried reformating it and it helps initially but then after 100GBs copied it starts crawling again. Don't know what's the best way to format it so it behaves like a new drive and doesnt have to re-write old stuff.

p.s. I didn't even know that such terrible drives existed. They should have red label on them saying "use for archive/cold storage only".

Comment: Agree, even when buying new one. I checked Seagate datasheets, there is no any info that HDD is SMR or PMR. I partially solved my issue with Level 2 cache (PrimoCache Defered Write). But it comes with risks.